# Bind DataGridView to a Chart.Series.Points YValues do not appear

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, mschart

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView TheGridView;
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series TheSeries;

TheGridView.DataSource=TheSeries.Points;
```

Everything shows up in the DataGridView except for the YValues.
I understand that the YValues are an Object[].

Is it possible to get the DataGridView to display the YValues?

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the values you are interested in in a List of anonymous type (best with named fields) and bind it..:

```
Series s = chart1.Series[0]

dataGridView1.DataSource = s.Points
                            .Select(x => new {X = x.XValue, Y = x.YValues[0] } )
                            .ToList();
```

(Lots of x'es in the select ;-)

Result:

[image]